# tooltip newline in a variable do not work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tooltip, newline

I would like to use a dynamic tooltip for a `commandButton` in an xhtml file, but I am unable to use new-line solutions in the xhtml file. This example works

```
<f:view xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:commandButton image="/resources/images/1.png" title="Line1&#013;Line2" actionListener="#{varBean.view}" />
</f:view>
```

but this does not, where `var.tooltip = "Line1&#013;Line2"`,

```
<f:view xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:commandButton image="/resources/images/1.png" title="#{var.tooltip}" actionListener="#{varBean.view}" />
</f:view>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Incredible, but I found a solution for my problem (the simpliest way works):

If var.tooltip String = `"Line1\nLine2"` then I see newlines in the tooltip :)

Maybe Standard JSF has no facilities for this, but Icefaces 3.2 has, or I do not know who, but it works! I hate that most of my Icefaces and JSF work is trying out different kind of syntax and solutions...